# mysql query inserting data multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

I have a table `log_Data` where i log searched keyword that user enter. I am facing an issue that mysql query is inserting data multiple time. query is super simple `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (id, keyword, date_adde) ...` but if user enter some word... the query will insert it and after some seconds it will insert again and sometimes it insert same record for 4 5 times.

How can i limit and make this insertion more accurate so i can avoid duplication and get better and more accurate search reports.

**EDIT**

inside my controller i have:

```
        if(isset($this->request->get['search']) && $this->request->get['search'] != ' '){
            $search_log = array(
                'keyword' => $this->request->get['search'],
                'source'  => '0', //0 for website and 1 for application
                'total_result' => $product_total
            );
            $this->model_catalog_product->searchLog($search_log);
        }
```

Inside my Model i have:

```
public function searchLog($data){
    $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO search_log SET keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($data['keyword']) . "', record = '" . (int)$data['total_result'] . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', source = '" . (int)$data['source'] . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "', date_added = NOW()");
}
```

attached an image where a customer searched for `heel` 'highlighted with black' is inserted 7 times with difference in few seconds... the customer originally searched for 1 time only... same as for other words as well...

[image]

Comment: Post your code in the question

Comment: Can you define what "duplicate" actually means here, by way of some sample data?  If you get 4 inserts, them most likely your code is making 4 inserts.

Comment: add an image to my question to elaborate ...

Comment: @Chilarai what code should i insert??? i mentioned the query..and its just simple insert query ...

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar, the data wont be inserted on its own unless the query is fired. Right? So can you show us the code section (if conditions, loops, etc) which leads to this issue. You have mentioned that you have issue in PHP

Comment: @Chilarai Sir please recheck my question ... i have everything ... code..results.. ig you need anything else...please tell me..

Comment: Is `date_added` the actual datetime of query execution start? This may be, for example, browser issue which re-sends its request after the answer had not receiving within some timeout...

Comment: @Akina , sir datetime is coming from MySQL function NOW(). so when query is executing... it pick the time and insert... my application at this point has nothing to do with response...

Comment: *datetime is coming from MySQL function **NOW()**. so when query is executing...* so 2-3 rows with the same query in your log table means 2-3 separate queries calls/executions. Search for intermediate application or service which re-sends the query,  and try to determine why (maybe this is due to some component setting?)... add MySQL connection_id() info into the log - does all query duplicates are executed in the same connection... anycase this is not MySQL issue.

Answer (score 0):

first, check your code. Secound make a unquiq key:

md5 ( keyword + date + hour )

Answer (score 0):

- try to avoid duplicate in any form by adding session protection add hidden input call it doupleprotection it is value come from randomization like rand(1000, 10000000000) or md5(time()) then save this value in session like  $_SESSION['doubleprotection']
- Afer submit form and before inserting in database compare input value with $_SESSION['doubleprotection'] , if equal do query then give $_SESSION['doubleprotection'] new value from rand(1000, 10000000000)
- if input value and $_SESSION['doubleprotection'] not equal stop query